# Term for piece of music without voice

Tags: single-word-requests, music

We call a piece of music with voice a *song*. What do we call a piece of music without voice? We *sing a song* but *play a XXX*.

Comment: It's still a song. If you want to specify a song with no lyrics, you can say *instrumental.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The term is "[instrumental](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/instrumental)".

> (music) Pertaining to, made by, or prepared for, an instrument,
>   especially a musical instrument; as, instrumental music, *distinguished from vocal music*.

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumental),

> An instrumental is a musical composition or recording without lyrics
>   or singing, although it might include some non-articulate vocal input;
>   the music is primarily or exclusively produced by musical instruments.

**However**, it doesn't fit well grammatically in your example sentence, which is understandable. One "sings a song" but one would not say he or she "plays an instrumental", unless it was somehow important that you distinguish the fact that you're excluding voice.

Musicians would more likely not make the distinction that the piece has vocals or not, and say:

- I am playing a *song*. (informal use of the word "song" includes any musical piece)
- I am playing a *piece*. (mostly used for classical)
- I am playing a *tune*. (mostly used for jazz and pop)
- I am playing a *number*. (mostly used for jazz)

Comment: I'd throw in a *melody*, too, in your examples.

Comment: Usually "melody" refers to a portion of a song, not a song itself. But there are definitely lots more synonyms I could add (just thought of "Ditty").

Comment: And if you're talking to Billy Joel's *piano man,* you say "play me a memory".

Comment: I've never heard "instrumental" used as a noun, but always as an adjective. I see the dictionary definition says it can be a noun. Is this usage common?

Comment: Yes, it's common.

Answer (score 2):

In general terms, you can call it *instrumental music*, but it would be more helpful to describe it in more detail, using terms such as *symphony, chamber music, concerto* and so on.

Comment: What would be a good name for an instrumental (well, electronic) piece by 16 bit Lolitas?